# NginX with GeoIP - what is returned for geo code when no mapping is found?

Tags: nginx, java, geoip

As the tests I conducted (using Java API to read `GeoIP.dat`, as well as local test) might be insufficient, I was wondering what happens on NginX when geo-ip module is configured, and when no IP to Country mapping is found..?

Example results using Java API:

```
151.38.39.114 -> IT  
12.25.205.51  -> US  
0.0.0.0       -> --
127.0.0.1     -> --
```

So, if I do this:

```
proxy_set_header GeoIP-CountryCode $geoip_country_code;
```

shall I also get `'--'` as the result, from NginX, or blank/null string, or something else when the mapping for the real IP might be missing (if at all possible..)?

(Side note: when testing this from local addresses such as `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.x.x`, Header value was always empty (null))